# Perform two counts (with different conditions) within the same SQL request

Tags: sql, select, count, case, sybase

I have to run the following two queries on a Sybase engine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS BTB_YES FROM FXMM_EVT_DBF WHERE M__INTID_ = '1.511' AND M_ISHEDGE = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS BTB_NO FROM FXMM_EVT_DBF WHERE M__INTID_ = '1.511' AND M_ISHEDGE = 0
```

Since I basically select the same set of information, i.e. :

```
SELECT M_ISHEDGE
FROM FXMM_EVT_DBF
WHERE M__INTID_ = '1.511'
```

and then I count on this column twice with two separate conditions, I kinda feel there is a way to have the result on the same single query, which would be great since the above queries must be run on several databases.

However, I'm being unable to get a joint result, probably because I'm not very good at SQL. My try was:

```
SELECT M_ISHEDGE
FROM FXMM_EVT_DBF WHERE M__INTID_ = '1.511'
CASE WHEN M_ISHEDGE = 1
    then count(*)
    else 0
END AS BTB_YES
CASE WHEN M_ISHEDGE = 0
    then count(*)
    else 0
END AS BTB_NO
```

but the above fails with the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT M_ISHEDGE
FROM FXMM_EVT_DBF WHERE M__INTID_ = '1.511'
CASE WHEN M_ISHEDGE = 1
    then count(*)
    else 0
END AS BTB_Y...
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'. [SQL State=ZZZZZ, DB Errorcode=156] 

Execution time: 0s

1 statement(s) failed.
```

and the SQL editor does not seem to recognize the keyword `THEN`, although it is part of the documentation, so probably because of some syntax mistake.

Comment: Since you want to count when M_ISHEDGE = 1 or 0 just group by that column. The count ill be calculate right and you ill get the results in two rows (one for every  M_ISHEDGE value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to move the case expression inside the count function like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN M_ISHEDGE = 1 then m_ishedge end) AS BTB_YES,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN M_ISHEDGE = 0 then m_ishedge end) AS BTB_NO
FROM 
    FXMM_EVT_DBF 
WHERE 
    M__INTID_ = '1.511'
```

Since the `case` expressions returns `null` if no `when` condition matches you can omit the `else` part (and `count` only counts non-null values).

Comment: Thanks, written like that it makes more sense; unfortunately it seems I can't really run it because my workbench does not recognize the keyword THEN and I really can't figure out why, since it should work as for the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315691.htm). I will try to figure out what goes wrong and come back to accept the answer once it will work, thank you!

Comment: Although the ANSI standard syntax should work (according to the docs you linked) you could try the alternate syntax using a searched case: `COUNT(CASE M_ISHEDGE WHEN 1 then M_ISHEDGE end) AS BTB_YES,`

Comment: I have finally used your solution (with the COUNT statement written as for the comments), and had to remove the final " ; " to make it work. Just if you want to correct it in the answer's body... thanks a lot jpw!

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with the `case` expression, but, as you noticed, the wrong syntax. The idea here is that `count` omits `null`s, so you'd want to apply the `count` function itself to the `case` expression:

```
SELECT COUNT (CASE M_ISHEDGE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS BTB_YES,
       COUNT (CASE M_ISHEDGE WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS BTB_NO
FROM   FXMM_EVT_DBF 
WHERE  M__INTID_ = '1.511'
```

Comment: Thanks, written like that it makes more sense; unfortunately it seems I can't really run it because my workbench does not recognize the keyword THEN and I really can't figure out why, since it should work as for the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315691.htm). I will try to figure out what goes wrong and come back to you as soon as I understand what's wrong, thank you!